# Focus gvim when opening a new file

Tags: 11.10, unity, gvim

I'm trying to switch from a mac dev environment to a linux dev environment, but I'm having a few problems. One of them is gvim. I would like to be able to double click a file in nautilus and then have gvim open it in a new tab. I already found how to open a file in a new tab here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323790/have-nautilus-open-file-into-new-gvim-buffer but it doesn't focus gvim yet.

Instead when I open a file unity 'wiggles' the gvim icon and I still have to alt-tab to it manually.

Is there a way to open a file in a new gvim tab *and* focus gvim at the same time? :)

Edit: I forgot to add that I'm using unity 2d on 11.10.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line in your `gvim.desktop` that says `Terminal=false` to `Terminal=true`.

Comment: This did seem to work a few times. It seems to stop working when I maximize my gvim screen and try to open another file :/. Not sure if that's it though...

Comment: will test further and let you know.

Comment: Thanks! After some more testing I can conclude that it works before  I maximize the gvim window. After maximizing it stops working until I log out and log in again. It doesn't seem to matter if I use Unity 2D or 3D

Comment: no, 2d and 3d should not mather, lets hope someone else gives a more steady answer or give me some more time to sort it out ;)

Answer (score -3):

I recommend switching to Gnome Shell. I can confirm there is no problem for me with Nautilus and gvim.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/gnome-shell-ubuntu-11-10-guide/

Comment: I actually quite like unity...